# how to construct chebyshev differentiation matrix of even/odd polynomial

Tags: spectral-method

I know there is efficient way to construct chebyshev differentiation matrix $D_N$. The idea is to fit the function $f(x)$ with a polynomial of $p_N(x)$ of order $N$, and use the derivative $p_N'(x)$ to approxiate $f'(x)$ at chebyshev points $x_0,..,x_N$.

I wonder if we know f(x) is an even function on $[-1,1]$, and we want to approximate $f(x)$ with a polynomial of only even terms $p_{2N}(x) = a_0 + a_2 x^2 + a_4 x^4 + ... a_{2N}x^{2N}$, is there an efficient way to construct the differentiation matrix $D_{2N}$?

Comment: There’s a matlab package called DMSUITE that computes various differentiation matrices, including the Chebyshev one. The code for the Chebyshev case is here: http://appliedmaths.sun.ac.za/~weideman/research/differ/chebdif.m

Comment: Thank you for the package! However, the package is for constructing general differential matrix. I would like to have one that is only for polynomials of even terms.